# Select columns based on another column in a different data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
AA <- c("GA","GA", "GA","GA","GA")
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
B <- c(5,4,3,2,1)
C <- c(2,3,4,5,1)
D <- c(4,3,2,1,5)
df <- data.frame(AA, A, B, C, D)
```

The other df is:

```
E <- c("B", "D")
F <- c("GA","GA")
df2 <- data.frame(E, F)
```

I would like to only select the columns from df based on the values from df2$E.
And that data frame would look like this:

```
AA <- c("GA","GA", "GA","GA","GA")
B <- c(5,4,3,2,1)
D <- c(4,3,2,1,5)
df3 <- data.frame(AA, B, D)
```

My current code below gives me a empty data frame with 0 obs and 5 variables

```
df3 <- df %>% filter(df %in% df2$E)
```

Any assistance in generating a code that works would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: How about `df[,c("AA",df2$E)]`?

Comment: Thanks Brian, this solution worked well for me.

Comment: @brian maybe you would like to answer the question rather as a comment?

Comment: To select columns use `select` i.e `df %>% select(AA, all_of(df2$E))`. `filter` is for rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can index via column names.

```
df[,c("AA",df2$E)]
```